# Nginx PEM_read_bio_X509 PEM_read_bio:bad end line

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

Unable to crack why this is happening. Certificate bundle file seems proper but receiving `PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Configuration file

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/abc-private.key;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/auth-api-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/auth-api-access.log;
}
```

Error in /var/log/nginx/error.log while starting nginx

`2020/01/07 17:13:32 [emerg] 4267#4267: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/bundle.crt": PEM_read_bio_X509() failed (SSL: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line)`

Comment: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in bundle.crt` gives the same error. Where did you get this file from?

Comment: @RichardSmith I redo the entire process and `openssl x509 -noout -text -in bundle.crt` command successfully executed. Actually I had received 4 cert files (1 domain cert and other intermediate files) - 
abc.crt, DigiCertGlobalCAG2.pem, DigiCertGlobalCAG2.pem.1 and RapidSSL_TLS_RSA_CA_G1.pem.

I appended them in a bundle.crt file using this command - 
`cat abc.crt RapidSSL_TLS_RSA_CA_G1.pem DigiCertGlobalCAG2.pem.1 DigiCertGlobalCAG2.pem > bundle.crt`

Earlier command was incorrect and there were some junk characters got appended

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, during initial SSL certificate installation or its renewal, the concatenation command corrupts certificate codes and reloading Nginx’s configuration files results in this error:

[image: Nginx/Apache error: 0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line]

If we open a file with concatenated certificate codes, we can see that closing tag -----END CERTIFICATE----- of one certificate and opening tag -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- of another one are joined in one line:

[image: Begin Certificate End Certificate Merged concatenated]

The issue fix is quite simple: use a text editor of your choice (for example, Nano or vim on Linux-based operating systems, Notepad on Windows, Textedit on Mac OS X) and create a line break between the two certificate codes, so that -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- tag starts with the next line:

[image: Fixed Concatenated Certificate]

Make sure that you count five dashes at the start and end of a footer and a header. Save the file and exit the text editor.

The Nginx configuration file can be reloaded with one of the following commands:

```
nginx -s reload
```

or
service nginx reload

The server should serve HTTPS from now on without any issues.

REFERENCE:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9855/2238/nginxapache-error-0906d066pem-routinespem_read_biobad-end-line/

Answer (score 0):

The first certificate block has had the invalid characters `1213PQJWENMASDASDDDAA` appended to its last line. Remove those and that cert can be parsed correctly. But it is a CA cert, specifically an intermediate cert for `C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, CN=DigiCert Global CA G2`, and not a valid server cert as the first cert in an nginx cert file should be.

The second block starts with the same first 5 lines (encoding 240 bytes) as the first block, perhaps copied, but the rest of it, although valid base64, appears to encode garbage and when combined doesn't produce anything even remotely resembling a valid cert. Remove it entirely. Then before the current first cert insert an actual server cert issued by that DigiCert intermediate if you have such; otherwise throw this away entirely and get correct certs from DigiCert or some other CA.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There were some extra characters appended at the end. Now the bundle.crt seems fine. I ran `openssl x509 -noout -text -in bundle.crt` and it didn't throw any error. neither the below command:
```[root@zmail nginx]# nginx -t
Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: However, when i start nginx using `service nginx start`, it fails with the below error:
```2020/01/08 13:17:55 [emerg] 7832#7832: cannot load certificate key "/etc/nginx/abc-private.key": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/nginx/abc-private.key','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)```

permission for abc-private.key
```[root@zmail nginx]# ls -ltr abc-private.key

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1751 Jan  6 08:59 abc-private.key
```

Comment: (1) `openssl x509` only reads the _first_ cert from a file that contains several, so that isn't a complete test; I _think_ `nginx -t` is more thorough but I'm not certain (2) `-rwxrwxrwx.` in `ls -l` means SELinux 'context' applies to the file; if the nginx service runs as other than root -- which it certainly should -- _and_ your system has SELinux enforcement active, that 'context' could cause a permission error. I don't remember the details on checking and changing SELinux context, but I've seen Qs on it and there are certainly man pages.